# Invalid Multiple Zip Files in in VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I try and upload a vsix package to the Visual Studio Gallery, I get the error message:

Invalid Multiple Zip Files in in VSIX

Does anyone know why this would be?

The package is at: http://sharpgl.codeplex.com/releases/view/82739 named 'SharpGL 2.0 Visual Studio Extension', and works fine on every machine I've tried it on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when a manifest's `<ProjectTemplate>` element's directory contains more than one ZIP file. For example, in my case, I had `<ProjectTemplate>ProjectTemplates</ProjectTemplate>` with this file system structure:

```
ProjectTemplates
|--CSharp
|  |--Web
|     |--Template.zip
|--VisualBasic
|  |--Web
|     |--Template.zip
```

The solution is to modify the manifest to contain as many `<ProjectTemplate>` elements as you have ZIP files, then structure the directories such that each `<ProjectTemplate>` doesn't lead to more than one ZIP:

```
<ProjectTemplate>T1</Proj    
<ProjectTemplate>T2</ProjectTemplate>

T1
|--CSharp
|  |--Web
|     |--Template.zip
T2    
|--VisualBasic
|  |--Web
|     |--Template.zip
```

Comment: Also, be sure you keep your path names short. The upload will complain if your paths are even moderately long.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer for any other readers out there.

Comment: You have no idea how long it took me to figure that out, too. :)

Comment: I've written a powershell script to do this automatically in case anyone needs it: http://www.dwmkerr.com/2014/03/managing-vsix-deployments-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upload your VSIX as a template? If it contains multiple templates, you must upload it as a "Tool".

Only VSIX's that contain a single template which can be instantiated via the New Project/Item Dialog can be classified on the VSGallery as a "template".

Comment: I get the same error message regardless of whether I attempt to upload the VSIX as a tool, control or template. Very confusing!

Comment: Yep, same here. There's a very ambiguous "answer" at Vaccano's link but I have no idea exactly what the fix is.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

[Invalid Multiple Zip Files in in VSIX.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vsx/thread/b155a689-75c2-41e4-aa47-c4b4e37374b4)

It did not fully solve my problem, but it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled nancy package based on VS versions below
https://github.com/talley/nancyfx/tree/master/Nancy%20VSIX%20Packages

Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)